# C++ Windows RPC how to define the MIDL can transmit null terminated char array

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, rpc

My project is use C++ Windows RPC to upload image(512*512) from client to server. I do not use WIN RPC before, So I tried some examples include send basic "Hello world" Message to server, but the huge issue is the function can't send unsigned char* include '\0'. I mean there are a lot of '\0' characters in the char array, they can't send to the server.

I think it is because I defined wrong MIDL function.

- I tried:

  ```
  void Output(
  [in, out, size_is(1048576), string] unsigned char* szString);
  ```
- another one

  void Output1(
  [in, length_is(1048576)] unsigned char[]);

But both can't work.

I use opencv3.2 to read image to Mat structure, and it can get Mat data and use memcpy to copy the Mat.data then create a new image in local client. But when I send Mat.data to server, the first of characters in the Mat.data is '\0'. All the Mat.data can't send to server.

```
My Client core code(It has include all require header) is

    Mat I = imread("U:\\normal.jpg", IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
if (I.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! Failed imread(): image not found" << std::endl;
    // don't let the execution continue, else imshow() will crash.
}
if (!I.data) {
    std::cout << "can't open or find image" << std::endl;
    //return -1;
}
I.convertTo(I, CV_32F);

I = (I.reshape(0, 1)); // to make it continuous

char tr[512*512*4];
memcpy_s(tr, 512 * 512 * 4, I.data, 512*512 * 4);
//snprintf(tr, 512*512*4,"%s", I.data);

Mat out = Mat(512,512, CV_32F, &tr[0]);
namedWindow("Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
imshow("Display window", out);
waitKey(5000);
```

...

```
RpcTryExcept
{
    std::clog << "Calling Open" << std::endl;
    output((unsigned char* )tr); // process the function, send data to server
    //output1((unsigned char* )tr);
}
```

Comment: You should be careful with large allocations like that. You may want to use `new` for larger character buffers.

Comment: @tadman Hi, thank you! I tried give larger buffers for the characters, but still can't send them to server. I also tried a smaller 128*128 icon, but when the character is '\0', it will stop at there..

Comment: That sounds like you have a few problems, one of which is your data is being interpreted as a NULL-delimited C-style string.